# Как через JS при полной загрузки web страницы нажать автоматически на определенную кнопку на сайте?

Tags: javascript

Сайт например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
Поставил расширение: https://addons.opera.com/ru/extensions/details/scripter-script-includer/
Какой код js вставить в расширение, чтоб при загрузки полной страницы скрипты выполнил нажатие на кнопку вопросы, а именно раздел "За месяц"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var sortBtnMonth = document.querySelector('.js-sort-preference-change[data-value="month"]');
   sortBtnMonth .click();
}, false);
```

[Загрузка документа и ресурсов](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)